# get a single row from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database with the data setup in categories, each category has a number of rows in it. What I need to do is get each row one at a time within a category.
here is the setup:
col 1  col 2     col3  ...
cat1   number   title ...
cat1   number   title ...
cat1   number   title ...
cat1   number   title ...
cat2   number   title ...
cat2   number   title ...

Number and title are key fields
I want to display the rows in each category ordered by title.
My initial query looks like

```
$query1 = "SELECT * from art where category = 'Florals'"; 
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect1,$query1) or die("mysqli_error());
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
```

I use the info captured in $row1.
I have been unable to display the records in order.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Where do you display anything?  What code do you have?  How do you fetch the next row?

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and looks clunky and out of place when used in new code.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work for you?

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1) )
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Tim, displaying it  and getting the rest of the row info is the issue. Your suggestion of the while loop gets the data but is ordered by the number not the title.

Comment: Do you know how to use `ORDER BY` in an SQL query?

Comment: Yes, I tried select * from art where category= catname ORDER by title no help it ordered them by number.

Comment: Tim, My mistake is that $row is an array which contains all the data in a single row. My issue is getting the data from elements of the array and assigning the ones I need to a variable. It seems PHP is different then C sharp.

Comment: You asked for an associative array ("mysqli_fetch_assoc"), so it should be `$row['number']` and `$row['title']`.

Comment: Tim, I solved everything but the order here is the code it is not ordered by title but by number.    $qry="select * from 'table' where category='category' order by 'title'";                      
 $connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);   
 $result = mysqli_query($connect,$qry) or die(mysqli_error());
      
     for ($i=0;$i < mysqli_num_rows($result);$i++)  // number of rows/records
     {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); 
    for($q=0;$q<9;$q++)
    {
    $new=$row[$q];
    echo " ".$new;
    }
    echo "<br>"; 
   }

Comment: Really, you should update the question with this so you can format the code properly.  Is that literally what you wrote?  Because neither `table` nor `title` should be in quotes.  If you really did quote `title`, then you are sorting each record by a string constant.